# Locating a button by className with Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I apologize if this is a newbie question, just starting out with web automation testing.

I want to test a login screen page. Finding the name and password textfields was easy (just used *by.model*), however I am having issues locating the login button with my script.

I googled around and I should be able to find an element by className using *element(by.css(.className))*, however this fails to work and I am always getting    `NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector(".btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block")`.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks you in advance,

**LoginBtn HTML:**

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" ng-disabled="loading">login</button>
```

**My code:**

```
describe('Test login', function() {
  var username = element(by.model('formData.email'));
  var password = element(by.model('formData.password'));
  var loginBtn = element(by.css('.btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block'));


  beforeEach(function() {
    browser.get('some site'); //hidden on purpose
  });

  it('should have a title', function() {
        username.sendKeys(1);
        password.sendKeys(2);
        loginBtn.click();


  });


});
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are checking for multiple classes, separate them with dots:

```
by.css('.btn.btn-lg.btn-primary.btn-block')
```

Though, I'd find the button by text - looks more reliable and readable:

```
by.xpath('//button[. = "login"]')
```

---

Also, think about assigning the button an `id` (if this is under your control) attribute to ease the testing process:

```
<button id="submitButton" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" ng-disabled="loading">login</button>
```

Then, it would be as easy as:

```
by.id('submitButton')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use only one class to find the locator

`by.css('.btn-primary')`

by class name

`by.className('btn-primary')`